# how to hightlight divs that not being hovered on hover

Tags: css, sass, hover

when i hover over a div, the background color changes to green but also when i hover i want the others divs to change to yellow

how i can make that with this html structure?

heres a [sample](https://codepen.io/IgorEstevaoo/pen/ZEbwLaO):

```
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>


    .box{
      background-color:yellow;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border:black solid 1px;
      margin: auto;
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
      transition: all 300ms;
      &:hover{
        background-color:green;
      }
    }
```

i want this when i hover:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would do that:

- put boxes in container div,
- set container default bgcolor red and hover bgcolor yellow,
- boxes default bgcolor none and hover bgcolor green